# double free or corruption (out) c

Tags: c, linked-list, runtime-error, free

I am writing a simple linked_list program to delete a node.
But I am getting runtime error:

> double free or corruption (out)

.
If I comment out free(t1) , then the error is gone.
Please explain my mistake.
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node* link;
};

int main()
{
    struct node a,b,c,d;
    struct node* head = &a;

    a.data=1;
    b.data=2;
    c.data=3;
    d.data=4;


    head->link = &b;
    head->link->link = &c;
    head->link->link->link = &d;
    d.link = NULL;

    struct node* new = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));   //new node creation
    new->data=5;

    struct node*t;
    t=head;

//deleting node with data=3

    while(t->link->data!=3)
        t=t->link;

    struct node* t1 = t->link;  //storing address of node to be deleted in t1 
    t->link = t1->link;         //breaking connection with node to be deleted

    free(t1);      //freeing the memory used by deleted node

    while(head)                         //Traversing...
    {
        printf("%d->",head->data);
        head = head->link;
    }
    printf("NULL"); 

return 0;       
}
```

Comment: You make a list of the four nodes `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. None of the nodes were allocated with `malloc`. You can only `free` what you `malloc`.

Comment: You cannot free variables with *automatic storage duration*, so you shouldn't mix pointers to them with dynamically allocated nodes.

Comment: The value assigned to  `new` is not used, aside from `new->data=5;`   It is never free'd.

Comment: It's often easier to use `calloc` at least for reasonably sized allocations, because it will zero the allocated memory, so you avoid a lot of potential randomly (because memory contents you `malloc` are "random") behaving Undefined Behavior cases (instead you get for example a semi-reliable segfault from NULL pointer).

Comment: Okay I understand. Thankyou @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Thankyou @AnttiHaapala